# What is the threshold for an answer to be considered an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852466/adding-time-duration-from-csv-file/30852560#30852560) as NAA, because I didn't feel that it answered the question. Briefly, the answer suggested a `for` loop (without mentioning how to structure it), then posted a tiny fragment of pseudocode that barely covered a fraction of an algorithm. I got the distinct impression that it was only posted as an answer because the user doesn't have enough rep for comments, so I flagged it as NAA. The flag was declined.

Is my understanding of "doesn't answer the question" not an accurate representation of the NAA flag? Does this flag only cover "hi that's a good question but I don't know how to fix it" or "what OS are you using" kinds of answers?

Comment: Yikes, somebody has to explain a for-loop?  NAA should be used for gibberish, downvote unhelpful answers.

Comment: You might just downvote it, NAA doesn't apply.

Comment: If you can explain to a co-worker why an answer isn't answering the question don't flag as NAA, just down vote. If you have no clue where to start or you get a blank stare from your co-worker when you try, it probably is NAA.

Answer (score 8):

It is an answer, not a very good answer, but it's still an answer.

The "Not An Answer" flag is for cases like:

1. Someone posts a follow up question in the answer box.
2. Someone posts a bare link with **no explanation** in the answer box.
3. Someone posts a request for more information from the OP in the answer box.

It's not for cases like:

1. "You should try this" followed by a half arsed attempt at some code.
2. Something that addresses only one small part of the problem.
3. Something that addresses the originally asked X problem, where Y solution should apply
4. ...

In cases like these you should down-vote. You can explain your down-vote if you wish but it's not compulsory.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, might collapse with your _point 2._ actually, but I'm not sure. What I'm sure about is, that the list could be extended (ad nauseam).